# Conditions on Quantum Numbers in Pseudo Harmonic Oscillator or Mie type potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, physical-chemistry

I have been trying to solve the problem of 3D Schrodinger equation with the following potential.

$$
V(r)= a_{0}+\frac{a_{1}}{r^{2}}+a_{3}r^{2}.
$$
 I got the following energy eigenvalues with quantum numbers $n_{r}$ and $l$, where $n_{r}=0$, $1$, $2$, $\ldots\quad$ If I am not wrong the values of $l$ are $0$, $1$, $2$, $\ldots\quad$ However I am not able fix the relationship between radial quantum number$(n_{r})$ and angular momentum quantum number$(l)$.$$E_{n_{r},l}= a_{0}+\sqrt{\frac{8\hbar^{2}a_{3}}{{m}}}\bigg[n_{r}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{1+4l(l+1)+\frac{8ma_{1}}{\hbar^{2}}}\bigg]$$

Now by looking at the energy eigenvalues , I am not able to tell values  $(l)$ would take for the given value of $(n_{r})$. Please explain me how do I fix the energy eigenvalues in the increasing order from the ground state specifying the quantum numbers.

I have used the series solution method to solve this eigenvalue problem.Let me attach the papers that I have read in this regard

"*Exact solutions of the Schrödinger equation via Laplace transform approach: pseudoharmonic potential and Mie-type potentials*emphasized text"*

"*Exact Polynomial Eigensolutions of the Schr¨odinger Equation for
the Pseudoharmonic Potential
Sameer M. Ikhdair and Ramazan Sever"*

Comment: I have no answer, but I am wondering why for negative $a_1$ and $a_3=0$  the energy eigenvalues are just constant. What are your assumptions on $a_1$ and $a_3$?

Comment: both the "a"s are positive constants

Comment: It would help if you included your derivation of $E_{n_r,l}$ in your question.

Comment: I am expecting an explanation for this problem...Can someone help me in this problem...I know people are in Christmas holidays...But if someone explain this It will be very helpful to me.